# Get bounding boxes of individual elements of a PathCollection from plt.scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

is there is a way to get bounding boxes of individual elements in the output of plt.scatter()? I can get offsets (i.e. x and y coordinates - which I have to begin with since I use them for plotting), and the sizes, but the sizes are not in data units, so even a hacky conversion from area to radius to get sizes of bboxes won't work...

Is there a good way to do this?

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')[:20]
f, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(tips["total_bill"], y=tips["tip"], s=(tips["size"]*3)**2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

`sc.properties()['offsets']`

```
array([[ 16.99,   1.01],
       [ 10.34,   1.66],
       [ 21.01,   3.5 ],
       [ 23.68,   3.31],
       [ 24.59,   3.61],
       [ 25.29,   4.71],
       [  8.77,   2.  ],
       [ 26.88,   3.12],
       [ 15.04,   1.96],
       [ 14.78,   3.23],
       [ 10.27,   1.71],
       [ 35.26,   5.  ],
       [ 15.42,   1.57],
       [ 18.43,   3.  ],
       [ 14.83,   3.02],
       [ 21.58,   3.92],
       [ 10.33,   1.67],
       [ 16.29,   3.71],
       [ 16.97,   3.5 ],
       [ 20.65,   3.35]])
```

`sc.get_sizes()`

`array([ 36,  81,  81,  36, 144, 144,  36, 144,  36,  36,  36, 144,  36,
       144,  36,  36,  81,  81,  81,  81])`

Comment: You can compute the size using `(sc.get_sizes()**0.5)/3`. This is the reverse operation of your `s=(tips["size"]*3)**2`

Comment: It will not be the actual radius in data units - radius in data units doesn't even make much sense with unequal aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you motivate why you need the bounding box in data units? Knowing the application of this might prevent not so useful answers. The general solution would be transform data to pixels, transform diameter to  pixels, create bounding box of center plus/minus half diameter, transform back to data coordinates.

Comment: To use in adjust_text, it can already accept any matplotlib object where you can get bboxes to avoid them, but would be great to add avoiding of scatter plot points, which can be of varying size.

Comment: Relying on diameter is not ideal also because people don't necessarily use circular markers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its generality this is far from simple. The PathCollection allows for different transforms as well as offset transformations. Also it might have one or several paths and sizes.

Fortunately, there is an inbuilt function `matplotlib.path.get_path_collection_extents`, which provides the bounding box of a `PathCollection`. We may use this to instead obtain the extent of each individual member by supplying a one-item list of each single path and looping over all of them.
Since the bounding box is in pixels, one will need to transform back to data coordinates at the end.

In the following is a complete function that would do all that. It will need to draw the figure first, such that the different transforms are set.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(432)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import get_path_collection_extents


def getbb(sc, ax):
    """ Function to return a list of bounding boxes in data coordinates
        for a scatter plot """
    ax.figure.canvas.draw() # need to draw before the transforms are set.
    transform = sc.get_transform()
    transOffset = sc.get_offset_transform()
    offsets = sc._offsets
    paths = sc.get_paths()
    transforms = sc.get_transforms()

    if not transform.is_affine:
        paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(p) for p in paths]
        transform = transform.get_affine()
    if not transOffset.is_affine:
        offsets = transOffset.transform_non_affine(offsets)
        transOffset = transOffset.get_affine()

    if isinstance(offsets, np.ma.MaskedArray):
        offsets = offsets.filled(np.nan)

    bboxes = []

    if len(paths) and len(offsets):
        if len(paths) < len(offsets):
            # for usual scatters you have one path, but several offsets
            paths = [paths[0]]*len(offsets)
        if len(transforms) < len(offsets):
            # often you may have a single scatter size, but several offsets
            transforms = [transforms[0]]*len(offsets)

        for p, o, t in zip(paths, offsets, transforms):
            result = get_path_collection_extents(
                transform.frozen(), [p], [t],
                [o], transOffset.frozen())
            bboxes.append(result.inverse_transformed(ax.transData))

    return bboxes



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.scatter(*np.random.rand(2,5), s=np.random.rand(5)*150+60)

# a single size needs to work as well. As well as a marker with non-square extent
sc2 = ax.scatter([0.2,0.5],[0.1, 0.7], s=990, marker="$\\rightarrow$")  

boxes = getbb(sc, ax)
boxes2 = getbb(sc2, ax)

# Draw little rectangles for boxes:
for box in boxes+boxes2:
    rec = plt.Rectangle((box.x0, box.y0), box.width, box.height, fill=False,
                        edgecolor="crimson")
    ax.add_patch(rec)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. I will try this tonight or tomorrow, but this looks like exactly what I need! I just wanted to mention, it looks like the rectangles are tiny bit shifted relative to the objects they are supposed to encompass, why is that?

Comment: That is due to marker stamping which got broken with mpl1.5 or 2 and since then no-one was able to repair. There are several issues about it (e.g. [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7262) or [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7233)), but it's not related to the code here and there is no easy solution to it. Note that this only occurs with Agg backends, not with Cairo based backends. However, with Cairo backends, the code from this question will show smaller boxes. As to why *that* is, I have no idea.

Comment: Note that [since 3.3 `inverse_transformed` is deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.3.0.html?highlight=deprecation#bboxbase-inverse-transformed), so `result.inverse_transformed(ax.transData)` should become `result.transformed(ax.transData.inverted())`.